# can the "cat" command use multi-processes

Tags: cat, multithreading

I need to merge bunch of files in a directory on a unix box that has 8 cores. I am looking for a fast way to merge these files. The cat command uses only one core... is there a way where I can make it use multiple cores for parallel processing.

Answer (score 6):

There is no effective way to parallelize an append I/O operation; each line *must* be written in turn.

Comment: Well, if you know the file sizes, I suppose you could in theory create a big sparse file and then chunk the parts into the right offsets.  However, this is still going to be I/O bound, so it doesn't offer any benefits.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, confirm the performance bottle-neck. Multi-thread is useless if disk io is your bottle-neck.

If you have a really fast disk or SSD, you can stat the files' lengths, calculate offsets, and use several dd commands.

Answer (score 0):

How about a script like this (with the sleeps to demonstrate how it parallelizes operations):

```
#!/bin/bash

eval exec 3\<<(echo FIRST FILE; sleep 3)
eval exec 4\<<(echo SECOND FILE; sleep 3)

cat <&3
cat <&4
```

It parallelizes the reading of the input files.  Note this is limited in many ways, and won't parallelize the output, but that can't be done anyway.

Here's a more complete example which processes all files in the current directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

fd=3
for file in *
do
    eval exec $fd\<<(cat $file)

    fd=$((fd + 1))
done

out_fd=3
while [ "$out_fd" -lt "$fd" ]
do
    cat <&${out_fd}
    out_fd=$((out_fd + 1))
done
```

The points above about performance are good; there's a chance this won't help at all.

**Update**
On further thought, this will only prefetch up to the pipe buffer size, 64k.  The following modification will pull all of the files into memory; if they can't fit, don't use it:

```
#!/bin/bash

fd=3
for file in *
do
    eval exec $fd\<<(content=$(<$file); echo "$content")

    fd=$((fd + 1))
done

out_fd=3
while [ "$out_fd" -lt "$fd" ]
do
    cat <&${out_fd}
    out_fd=$((out_fd + 1))
done
```